# unix (cygwin) fifo buffering

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cygwin

Looking for an intercepting proxy made with netcat I found [this script](http://notes.tweakblogs.net/blog/7955/using-netcat-to-build-a-simple-tcp-proxy-in-linux.html):

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ $# != 3 ]
then
    echo "usage: $0 <src-port> <dst-host> <dst-port>"
    exit 0
fi

TMP=`mktemp -d`
BACK=$TMP/pipe.back
SENT=$TMP/pipe.sent
RCVD=$TMP/pipe.rcvd
trap 'rm -rf "$TMP"' EXIT
mkfifo -m 0600 "$BACK" "$SENT" "$RCVD"
sed 's/^/ => /' <"$SENT" &
sed 's/^/<=  /' <"$RCVD" &
nc -l -p "$1" <"$BACK" | tee "$SENT" | nc "$2" "$3" | tee "$RCVD" >"$BACK"
```

Which work nicely, as expected.

Since I need to look closely to the encoding used, hence the actual bytes passing, I tried to change some lines to use `hexdump -vC`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ $# != 3 ]
then
    echo "usage: $0 <src-port> <dst-host> <dst-port>"
    exit 0
fi

TMP=`mktemp -d`
BACK=$TMP/pipe.back
SENT=$TMP/pipe.sent
RCVD=$TMP/pipe.rcvd
trap 'rm -rf "$TMP"' EXIT
mkfifo -m 0600 "$BACK" "$SENT" "$RCVD"
( hexdump -vC | sed 's/^/ => /' ) <"$SENT" &
( hexdump -vC | sed 's/^/<=  /' ) <"$RCVD" &
nc -l -p "$1" <"$BACK" | tee "$SENT" | nc "$2" "$3" | tee "$RCVD" >"$BACK"
```

Now it's not working anymore. Actually, I've lost the "realtime" feature of the previous script. Every byte sent is dumped in a single batch; then every byte received in another batch; and this all only after the connection is closed.

I'm suspecting some sort of buffering occurs in the pipe (`|`), but I'm not sure how to:

1. test this hypotesis;
2. fix the script to make it work in realtime again.

PS1. I'm using cygwin.
PS2. `sh --version` outputs:

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
```

**Edit:**

Removind the `| sed ...` part (that is, leaving only `hexdump -vC <"$SENT"` and `hexdump -vC <"$RCVD"`) the realtime feature is back, increasing my suspicion over the pipeline operator. But the output turns out to be confusing since sent and received bytes are mixed.

Comment: Does using `sed -u` help?

Comment: Yes, buffering occurs in each pipe in the hexdump pipelines.  There probably isn't a way to make it work 'in real time' again.

Comment: @EtanReisner no, it didn't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm also afraid of that; in reality I was expecting the buffering of pipes, so the behavior of the second script (the script of mine) is what I *DO* expect; what I didn't is the behavior of the original script.

Comment: Does the `unbuffer` utility from the `expect` package help?

Answer (score 0):

Still I couldn't manage to resolve the buffering (?) issue, but I could change the `hexdump` invocation to render the `sed` unnecessary:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ $# != 3 ]
then
    echo "usage: $0 <src-port> <dst-host> <dst-port>"
    exit 0
fi

TMP=`mktemp -d`
BACK=$TMP/pipe.back
SENT=$TMP/pipe.sent
RCVD=$TMP/pipe.rcvd
trap 'rm -rf "$TMP"' EXIT
mkfifo -m 0600 "$BACK" "$SENT" "$RCVD"
hexdump -v -e '" => %08.8_Ax\n"' -e '" => %08.8_ax  " 8/1 "%02x " "  " 8/1 "%02x "' -e '"  |" 16/1 "%_p" "|\n"' <"$SENT" &
hexdump -v -e '"<=  %08.8_Ax\n"' -e '"<=  %08.8_ax  " 8/1 "%02x " "  " 8/1 "%02x "' -e '"  |" 16/1 "%_p" "|\n"' <"$RCVD" &
nc -l "$1" <"$BACK" | tee "$SENT" | nc "$2" "$3" | tee "$RCVD" >"$BACK"
```

Yes, the new `hexdump` looks ugly, but works.

This question for me is now open just for the sake of curiosity. I'm still willing to give the "correct answer" points to the one who explains (and fixes) the buffering (?) behavior.